# Unable to detect null input from readline in C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to do error handling so that if someone just hit enter and didnt input a value it would ask for a proper value. It appears that just pressing enter returns a value via readline although i cant determine what value
here is my code which is supposed to handle null values

```
        public static string StringTester(string? input)
        {
            string output;
            if (input != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not null nani");
            }
            if (input == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please input valid value");
                output = StringTester(Console.ReadLine());

            } else if (input.Contains('\n') ^ input.Contains(' ') ^ input.Contains('\r'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please input valid value");
                output = StringTester(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else
            {
                output = input;
            }
            return output;
        }
```

I tried to find the return value on google and through the documentation by microsoft on readline however none came up. I thought maybe it is reading a new line so i added a new line into the error handling.

Comment: Do you really mean to use the [`^`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) operator, or do you want [`||`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-)?

Answer (score 2):

`Console.ReadLine` will return a `string` containing the characters that the user typed before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If they didn't type any characters then that `string` will be empty, i.e. `Console.ReadLine` will return `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-7.0) for situations like this.

It will check if the string is null, or empty ("")

Comment: May be `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(...)` is even better.

Answer (score 0):

For check an empty value from input you have to use:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(*yourString*)){//error handling}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine` will return an empty string, if the user doesn't enters anything. To check for null, you can use the [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-7.0)`